# Проверка данных GET запроса

Tags: php

Есть ссылка `mysite.ru/user564556`, где 564556 - цифры. полученные из GET запроса (номер страницы пользователя). С цифрами все работает нормально, страницу определенного пользователя показывает.

Фильтрую данные GET запроса так:

```
 mysql_real_escape_string(trim(
   htmlspecialchars(addslashes(strip_tags($_GET['user'])))
 ));
```

Короче, навертел все, что только возможно. Но когда передаю вместо цифр строку,

```
 <script>alert(/текст/)</script>
```

то окно с сообщением "/текст/" выводит на экран, а на фоне этого окна ошибка

> "Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access /user on this server."

Вопрос: это нормально или есть какой-то недочет в фильтрации, который я не учел?

Comment: Может проще `preg_match` и `/^/user(\d+)$/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы делаете ересь)

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^user([^/]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1
```

тут все равно бесполезно фильтровать, кому надо - отправят напрямую "`index.php?user=<script>...`";

index.php вариант 1, строгая и правильная фильтрация

```
<?
if (empty($_GET['user'])) die('юзер не указан');
$user = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $_GET['user']);
if ($user != $_GET['user']) die('юзер содержит недопустимые символы');
// $user - идентификатор
?>
```

index.php вариант 2, быстрая фильтрация

```
<?
if (!($user = (string)preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', @$_GET['user']))) die('юзер не указан');
// $user - идентификатор
?>
```

В обоих случаях переменную $user можно засовывать в запрос и выводить. В первом случае при некорректном вводе скрипт умрет, во втором - принудительно приведет в нормальный вид.

```
$_GET['user']    v1                 v2
''               die(empty)         die(empty)
'ololo'          ololo              ololo
'lol!@#$'        die(incorrect)     lol
'!@#$'           die(incorrect)     die(empty)
```